# a simple payroll system using linked list c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

i am simply creating a payroll system that has a employee name and a working hours for that employee.. the data is supposed to be stored in a linked list data structure, but i can not connect the linked list to the object of the class employee, i tried making the pay roll linked list (i.e empList) as a static member so that all the objects of the class can use the same list object and data can be stored but once i compile my code i get an error of "undefined reference to employee::empList" at line 130 that is the last line of constructor, same error on line 150 that is a print pay roll function.. where ever i am trying to call any payRollLinkedList class's function in employee class it gives error.. bottom line is that all i want is to data be stored in a doubly linked list of employees and i can not access the list.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class payRollLinkedList;
    class node
    {
    private:
        node* previousPointer;
        string name;
        int hoursWorked;
    node* nextPointer;
    friend class payRollLinkedList;
    public:
        explicit node(const string argName, const int argHoursWorked)
        : previousPointer{nullptr}, name{argName}, hoursWorked{argHoursWorked}, nextPointer{nullptr}
        {}
    };
    class payRollLinkedList
    {
    private:
        node* headPointer{nullptr};
        node* tailPointer{nullptr};
        node* getNewNode(const string argName, const int argHoursWorked)
        {
            return new node(argName, argHoursWorked);
        }
    public:
        void addAtBack(const string argName, const int argHoursWorked)
        {
            node* newNode{getNewNode(argName, argHoursWorked)};
            if(isEmpty())
            {
                headPointer = tailPointer = *newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                tailPointer->nextPointer = newNode;
                newNode->previousPointer = tailPointer;
                tailPointer = newNode;
                newNode = nullptr;
                delete newNode;
            }
        }
        bool deleteNode(string argName)
        {
            node* currentPointer{headPointer};
            if(isEmpty())
            {
                cout <<"the list is already empty\n";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                while(currentPointer != nullptr)
                {
                    if(currentPointer->name == argName)
                    {
                        if(currentPointer == headPointer)
                        {
                            node* tempPointer{headPointer};
                            headPointer = headPointer->nextPointer;
                            tempPointer->nextPointer = nullptr;
                            headPointer->previousPointer = nullptr;
                            delete tempPointer;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(currentPointer == tailPointer)
                        {
                            node*tempPointer{tailPointer};
                            tailPointer = tailPointer->previousPointer;
                            tempPointer->previousPointer = nullptr;
                            tailPointer->nextPointer = nullptr;
                            delete tempPointer;
                            break;
                        }
                        node* tempPointer{currentPointer};
                        node* nextPtr{tempPointer->nextPointer};
                        currentPointer = currentPointer->previousPointer;
                        currentPointer->nextPointer = nextPtr;
                        nextPtr->previousPointer = currentPointer;
                        tempPointer->nextPointer = nullptr;
                        tempPointer->previousPointer = nullptr;
                        currentPointer = nullptr;
                        nextPtr = nullptr;
                        delete tempPointer;
                        delete currentPointer;
                        delete nextPtr;
                    }
                    else
                        currentPointer = currentPointer->nextPointer;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        void print()
        {
            if(isEmpty())
            {
                cout <<"nothing to show\n";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                node* currentPointer{headPointer};
                while(currentPointer != nullptr)
                {
                    cout <<currentPointer->name <<"\t";
                    currentPointer = currentPointer->nextPointer;
                }
            }
        }
        bool isEmpty()
        {
            return headPointer == nullptr? true : false;
        }
    };
    class employee
    {
    private:
        string name;
        int hoursWorked;
        static payRollLinkedList empList;
    public:
        employee()
        : name{""}, hoursWorked{0}
        {}
        employee(string argName, int argHoursWorked)
        {
            name = argName;
            hoursWorked = argHoursWorked;
            empList.addAtBack(name, hoursWorked);
        }
        void printPayRoll()
        {
            empList.print();
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        employee emp("usman", 12);
        employee emp1("ali", 12);
        emp.printPayRoll();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have an employee list as a member of the employee class?

Comment: i assumed i would just sent name and working hours as parameters from within the employee class to the payRollList member functions add and delete.. and to access those functions of payRollList in employee class i needed an payRollList object that is the employee list.

Comment: `delete tempPointer; delete currentPointer; delete nextPtr;` -- Why in `delete` node, you're deleting 3 nodes?  Draw a deletion of a node on paper using boxes as the node and lines as the links.  The only thing that should be done is to link the node that is previous to the one to delete with the next node of the one to delete.  Then a *single* delete of the node that is now unlinked.

Comment: i am deleting these 3 pointers after declaring them nullptr's.. that before deleting they have nothing to do with the linked list any node, the tempPointer was pointing to the node to be deleted, the currentPointer was assigned the address of tempPointer->previousPointer and the nextPtr was pointing to the node next to the node to be deleted. i ran the function afterwards it was working perfectly fine sir.

Comment: Note that when using pointers, there is no guarantee that your code is working "fine" because you see no error.  Do you see how convoluted you've written the `delete` code?  What in the description I mentioned is difficult to understand?  If you get any tutorial on linked list deletion, you see a single node deleted with the deleted node unhooked from the list, not three separate nodes deleted.  It seems you didn't follow a visual plan (*i.e. draw a linked list on paper) -- if you did, you would have been hard pressed to come up with the code you came up with.  Trying to be serious, not harsh.

Comment: What I'm saying is that other than the special case of the head and tail pointers, a deletion should be 1) hook the previous node to the next of the node to delete, then 2) delete the node to delete.  That's it, nothing else.

Comment: i had a visual plan, i always solve a problem by drawing it out, but it sometimes gets complicated. Anyhow i have just started data structures and had taken only one class.. i obviously dont know how would i structure my code when using a data structure yet, so i will obviously work on it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you implement the list yourself? C++ provides `std::vector` or `std::list`, which should work just fine for your described use case.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

You need to define static member of class at global scope (out of class).
i suggest you to split your code .h and .cpp files and define the member in .cpp file.

```
payRollLinkedList employee::empList;
```